# tweepy/twitter get all tweets from a location:

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy

I have the following questions about tweepy python module

1.I am trying to retrieve all tweets for a specific location. I am able to do this by using tweepy python module (streaming API), but I get only those tweets whose geo locations are enabled, which means I would loose rest of the tweeter’s tweet who have not enabled their geo location. Is there a better way to retrieve all the tweets, given a location?

2.I use Stream.Sample method to retrieve all the tweets, Can someone tell me about the parameters used in sample method? I see count, and async as parameters. Now what should we specify here?

3.What does firehose method in tweepy.Stream do?

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: What tweets do you want to receive? If a tweet doesn't have location information, it's pretty obvious that it can't be searched by location, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, I was thinking if twitter gives the locations based on the IP addresses, I might be wrong or even absurd but just thinking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If *tweepy* doesn't have a feature you need, you can always access Twitter directly with an HTTP request.  The full Twitter REST API is described here:  https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api

The ones that seem relevant to your interest are:

- `GET trends/:woeid` which looks up tweets by [woeid](http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/geoplanet/), a Yahoo Identifier for collecting information about a given place/landmark/etc.
- `GET geo/id/:place_id` which only mines geotagged tweets.
- There is documentation of all the information available for a `GET` request but the IP address is not among the available fields:  https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search .
- Lastly, Twitter has a [location search FAQ](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/places/finding-tweets-about-places) that may be of interest.

Comment: Is there any way to get the number of tweets for that location?